# Ease Animation In Slider

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand animations better. To be truthful I don't really get keyframes, regardless of how many tutorials I read. So as an experiment to try and learn, I tried making a simple box slider that basically fades in each layer and repeats. I want to be able to fadein from layer to layer then repeat process.

Here's the closest I could get.

HTML

```
<div class="index"></div>
<div class="index"></div>
<div class="index"></div>
<div class="index"></div>
<div class="index"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
div:first-of-type {
    background: red;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: green;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: blue;
    animation-delay: 10s;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: yellow;
    animation-delay: 15s;
}
div:last-of-type {
    background: orange;
    animation-delay: 20s;
}
.index {
    animation: index 5s ease-in infinite;
}
@keyframes index {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve my desired effect?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2rxujkt/1/

Comment: How does it work? Fade from red to green and so on? Do there have to be  5 index layers or just one?

Comment: Ingore the color, I just didn't want to take the time to add background images. But in a nutshell, fade from one div to another. Not necessarily  from color to color.

Comment: My logic originally was fade in each div from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`, and make it appear for each div by adding a animation delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 3rd key:

```
@keyframes index {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2rxujkt/2/

Comment: The problem with this method is that shows red again before each new fadein. Also, it's doesn't start again, it just repeats the last div.

Answer (score 0):

CSS z-index property is needed. But also a little of JS. Here is a good example.
http://codepen.io/peterwestendorp/pen/LbiwD

Via JS you just apply the `'fx'` class and then via CSS you use:

```
.fx:first-child + div ~ div  {
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Also good point is to use animation like this:

```
@keyframes index {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to do this without JavaScript.